# Jenkins results: Need a "single" summary report of last run of jobs

Tags: jenkins, report, jobs

We have multiple jenkins-jobs scheduled at roughly near the same time every night.

I would like a report-summary of status to be available to me / or sent to me.

I do not repeatedly want to do a walk through test suite every day.

Much appreciated any advice on topic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Global Build Stats](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin) plugin might fit your needs. It does not support scheduled email, but if you need that you could use the rest API it exposes to write your own.

Comment: Nice suggestion thanks. Just did a trial. When i pick a section in the chart the resulting table hot links are not reachable they are slightly wrong ? Any idea why this is ?